# FFMPEG store method: Separated fields?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG with GPU h264_nvenc codec to upscale MPEG2 interlaced files.
h264_nvenc generate h264 with the store method: Separate fields (in mediaInfo) instead of the store method: Interleaved fields. These files with separate fields seems to be incompatible with tools like GVG Edius. How to change this store method?

with ffmpeg version N-92103-gebc3d04b8d Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813

Command FFMPEG:

```
 -ss 00:14:45  -hwaccel cuda   -c:v mpeg2_cuvid  -i "input.mpg" -t 00:00:10 -vf "scale=if(gt(dar\,1.6)\,1920\,1460):1080:flags=lanczos:interl=1" -c:v h264_nvenc  -pix_fmt nv12 -flags +ilme+ildct -b:v 16M -maxrate:v 22M -bufsize:v 8M -profile:v high -level:v 4.1 -rc:v vbr  -coder:v cabac -f mp4 -y "inputUpscaled_GPU.MP4"
```

mediainfo testUpscale_GPU.MP4:

```
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 10 s 0 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 17.8 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 22.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 460 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Original frame rate                      : 50.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan type, store method                  : Separated fields
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.451
Stream size                              : 21.2 MiB (99%)
Codec configuration box                  : avcC
```